# Same text, one vs two spans shifts the letters

Tags: html, css, fonts

For some fonts, if I split text across two spans, it looks different. The letters shift slightly. I'm wondering why this happens, and how to stop it.

This doesn't happen for all fonts, but here on my Mac with Verdana I see it.  These two look different:

```
<span>Rob</span>
<span>R</span><span>ob</span>
```

Here's some example code where you can click a button and watch it shift. Depending on your OS you might need to change the font though.

https://jsfiddle.net/6dtk2uoy/

**Update**: it appears to be browser specific. It's only happening for me in Safari, but not Chrome or Firefox. Maybe I should delete this question and report a bug instead.

Comment: Nothing happens here, using latest FF in win10

Comment: Yup, only Safari is doing it to me. I updated question.

Comment: sounds like a job for http://bugreport.apple.com